# Scroling table in Bootrstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I use `bootstrap v4.5.3`.  I want to implement a scrolling table in which there are many records. And at the bottom of the page of the link to the next and previous page of the table. I get it so that the table goes under Footer. How to make sure that the table is between Menubar and Footer and could not scroll through the browser scrollbar, but with its own. I put the picture.
[image]

Comment: you explain a generally request but I can suggest to you search about bootstrap table and bootstrap paginate, for implement paginate login you think and search about functionality of pageinate (think about pageNumber , currentPage and totalPages and relation between these terms)

Comment: @masoud no no, I probably explained it better. All I need is for the table to be scrollable, with a menu above and below and a simple footer. I have the bottom of the table going beyond the footer. and the last entry is not visible.